# my clion run default"CreateProcess error=216"

Tags: clion

Error running 'random': Cannot run program "C:\Users\31665\CLionProjects\random\cmake-build-debug\random.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\31665\CLionProjects\random\cmake-build-debug"): CreateProcess error=216, 该版本的 %1 与你运行的 Windows 版本不兼容。请查看计算机的系统信息，然后联系软件发布者。[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BWZH.png)